# Is there a way to launch a command a new tab with cmder?

Tags: cmder

I want to make a little script that opens two npm scripts, each one in their own tab but I am not able to find a way to do this.

If I do `cmd -new_console` it opens a new tab with cmd not cmder

If I do `{cmd::Cmder} -new_console` it fails

If I do `Cmder -new_console` it opens a new tab **and** a new Cmder window.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want:

```
cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" -new_console
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`Cmder -new_console /single`

I got this from the error that cmder gives you when you enter an incorrect flag.